# Realloc segfault - invalid old size

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, realloc

I have a function in which the second pass gives me segfault every time and I have no idea how to fix it. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
char* testBefore(int k){
   char* bin;
   bin = calloc(1,1);

   while(k > 0) {
      bin = realloc(bin, strlen(bin)*sizeof(char)+1);
      bin[strlen(bin) - 1] = (k % 2) + '0';
      bin[strlen(bin)] = '\0';
      k = k / 2;
   }
   printf("\n%s.", bin);
   return bin;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample to fix.

```
char* testBefore(int k){
    char* bin;
    int i = 0;
    bin = calloc(1,1);

    while(k > 0) {
        bin = realloc(bin, (i+1)*sizeof(char)+1);
        bin[i++] = (k % 2) + '0';
        k = k / 2;
    }
    bin[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n%s.", bin);//reversed
    return bin;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

strlen does not give the size of the array.

This will not enlarge the memory:

```
bin = realloc(bin, strlen(bin)*sizeof(char)+1);    //0+1 == 1
```

And then calling strlen on that memory will produce undefined behavior since the result
 `strlen(bin) - 1` will be negative:

```
 bin[strlen(bin) - 1] = (k % 2) + '0';    //bin[0-1]
```

In you case you should use an extra variable that keeps the size of the allocated memory.

Comment: Uh, what does it give then?

Comment: @user3885166 The length of a string.

Comment: What's the difference, I thought char* is a string in c?

Answer (score 1):

```
   char* bin;
   bin = calloc(1,1);
```

Now `bin` points to a 1-byte space containing `0`.

```
   while(k > 0) {
      bin = realloc(bin, strlen(bin)*sizeof(char)+1);
```

Not sure about what `k` would be. Anyway, `strlen(bin)` == 0 since `bin[0] == '\0'`.
Afterward, `bin` points to another 1-byte space storing `0`.

```
      bin[strlen(bin) - 1] = (k % 2) + '0';
```

Here `strlen(bin)` returns `0` again, and accessing `bin[0-1]` is obviously out-of-bound and thus undefined behavior happened.